# PHP Regex - Matches multiple items after Positive Lookbehind

Tags: php, regex

I have this HTML

```
<ul class="my-list"><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>

<ul class="other-list"><li>ItemA</li><li>ItemB</li><li>ItemC</li></ul>
```

I want to get each `<li>` that's under the class "my-list" and tried to use Positive Lookbehind like this:

```
preg_match_all( '/(?<=my-list">).*(<li>.+<\/li>)/Ui', $text, $matches );
```

But I only get the first `<li>` like this:

```
array(
  0 => array(1
    0 => <li>Item1</li>
  )
)
```

How to get each of the list item? Expected result:

```
array(1
  0 => array(1
    0 => <li>Item1</li>
    1 => <li>Item2</li>
    2 => <li>Item3</li>
  )
)
```

Thanks

Comment: It's parser time!

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using a parser instead:

```
<?php

$data = <<<HTML
<ul class="my-list"><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>

<ul class="other-list"><li>ItemA</li><li>ItemB</li><li>ItemC</li></ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//ul[@class = 'my-list']/li") as $node) {
#                                             ^^^
    echo $node->nodeValue . "\n";
}

?>
```

Which yields

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

See [**here for more information**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_dom.asp). Alternatively, [**this project**](https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser) looks interesting as well.

---

As for changing (editing) values, just change a few lines:

```
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); 
# removes the doctype string
```

Then change e.g. the node value of an element and output it afterwards:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//ul[@class = 'my-list']/li") as $node) {
    $node->nodeValue .= "###";
}

$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

This will yield

```
<ul class="my-list">
<li>Item1###</li>
<li>Item2###</li>
<li>Item3###</li>
<ul class="other-list">
<li>ItemA</li>
<li>ItemB</li>
<li>ItemC</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's neat, I never knew there is such method. But how do you replace a value with that? I was planning to do a `preg_replace`

Comment: @hrsetyono: Updated the answer - see the lower part.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is much cleaner than regex. I've been using regex for scrapping website for far too long...

Comment: @hrsetyono: You might want to upvote and/or accept an answer that helped you...

Answer (score 0):

```
$text='<ul class="my-list"><li>Item1</li><li>Item2</li><li>Item3</li></ul>

<ul class="other-list"><li>ItemA</li><li>ItemB</li><li>ItemC</li></ul>';

preg_match( '/<ul class="my-list">(.*?)<\/ul>/i', $text, $matches );
preg_match_all( '/(<li>.+<\/li>)/Ui', $matches[0], $matches1 );

var_dump($matches1[0]);
```

Result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "<li>Item1</li>"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "<li>Item2</li>"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "<li>Item3</li>"
}
```